# Creating Forms in Javascript-Length is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

So I feel silly asking this question, but am currently a high school student in Coding that needs help. We're working on a project with the same requirements for all people, so I took some code that worked for my friend to use for a form; however, I keep running in the problem that my 'length is undefined' and therefore, will not do what I want it to. My code is below:

HTML:

What toppings do you like on your ice-cream?

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Whip Cream">Whip Cream
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Sprinkles">Sprinkles
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Fruit">Fruit
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Hot Fudge/Caramel">Hot Fudge/Caramel
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Other">Other
    </label>
  </div>

  <input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit">

  <div id="r">

  </div>
```

Script:

```
var form = document.forms.example;
//This points to the form called "example" in HTML

form.addEventListener("submit",nameDisplay,false);

function nameDisplay(event) { 

    event.preventDefault();
    var person = {

        name: form.username.value,
    }

    var text = "<p> Mmmm..." + person.name +" sounds yummy!</p>";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;


}

var l = [];

for(i = 0; i < form.food.length; i++) {


    if(form.food[i].checked) {
        l.push(form.food[i].value);
    }
    console.log("loop");
}

    console.log(l);

    person.food = l;

    console.log(person.food);

var text = "<p>You like" + person.food.join(",") + "on your ice-cream.</p>";

document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = text;
```

NOTE: I have two forms, hence the first part of javascript, but I thought maybe the problem lies within one thing is overriding another and what not or I'm missing something. I am only having problems with the ice-cream one though. Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the funky format...pretty noob to this site too lol

Comment: Can you make this into a [JSFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: also, I don't see the code where you declare your form.

Comment: So I think I did it on JS fiddle....and I just added the whole thing so you guys can see. Thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/1yy9vo4u/

Comment: Also Sebas, I didn't add the form tag on HTML because it seemed to work without it for my friend...but I can try adding it to see if it works!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access the checkboxes, form.food is not that form at all. The checkboxes aren't even part of the form. Try using console.log or breakpoints using the browser developer tools to see what you are accessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working version of your code

Issues found:

- form tag was missing
- There was no username input yet person needed it
- The code you added
  after your friend's was outside the nameDisplay function
- There was no "result" div

Other concerns you may want to review

- Is there a need to wrap your input's in divs?
- No need for the `food` variable
- I'd love to see the loop replaced with a `filter` and `some`
- Bro, are you sure im not doing your homework?

```js
var form = document.forms.example; //This points to the form called "example" in HTML

form.addEventListener("submit", nameDisplay, false);

function nameDisplay(event) {

  var food = [];

  for (i = 0; i < form.food.length; i++) {

    if (form.food[i].checked) {
      food.push(form.food[i].value);
    }
  }

  var text = "<p>You like " + food.join(",") + " on your ice-cream.</p>";

  document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<h3>What would you like on your Ice Cream?</h3>
<form id="example">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Whip Cream">Whip Cream
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Sprinkles">Sprinkles
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Fruit">Fruit
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Hot Fudge/Caramel">Hot Fudge/Caramel
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input name="food" type="checkbox" value="Other">Other
    </label>
  </div>

  <input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit">

  <div id="r">

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The length undefined problem is fixed, but it still doesn't paste to the HTML page like I want and now I have a name box I do not want...lol coding is tricky.

Comment: Interesting, a string in your code congratulated the user for making a pick, and the `person` object wanted a name. Beyond that, how did you expect it to be pasted in the page?

Comment: Basics...my h3 asked the question while the checkboxes gave your options. You hit the submit button and below it says" You like ______ on your ice cream." lol I'm sorry if I confused you or I just don't understand...if all else fails...I can always try a different form lol.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's still not working which tells me something else is blocking it. More unknowns for me lol. Thank you!(:

Comment: Welcome to programming, if it works too soon it will break later. Note that you can actually run the code I posted in the answer, it may give you a clue, enjoy the journey